# Pathauto is converting special characters (accented) by interrogation points

Tags: path-aliases

I created a Drupal website some years ago and everything was working well until now.

But since yesterday (when the client came back to me), the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module is now replacing all accented characters by quoting marks in URL aliases.

For example for this node, the URL alias was correct and it was updated.

[image]

But now, if I check the option "Generate automatic URL alias", then the "é" character is replaced by ??, as you can see there.

[image]

Any idea why this is occurring? How can I fix that?

Comment: Which Drupal version? A possible fix for Drupal 7 might be the [transliteration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration). It integrates with pathauto and can automatically convert paths into 'regular letters' (turning mélanie into melanie).

Comment: Thank you @Neograph734, I will check. But it's pretty curious why everything was working well until this week and now it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you, but any update of drupal (modules) or server software could have something to do with this. Without knowing what you did with your site and server, there is no way for us to tell what could be the root of this.